# Is symlink's target relative to the destination's parent directory and if so, why?

Tags: symlink

I've got the following file structure:

```
build/
client/
  –> index.js
```

And when I try to create a symbolic link named "client" inside the build directory that refers to the client directory in the cwd like so

```
// Fails
$ pwd
/home/user/
$ ln -s client build/client 
$ stat build/client/index.js
stat: build/client/index.js: stat: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I get the ELOOP error displayed above. When I change the target path to be relative to the destination path, all is good:

```
// Works
$ pwd
/home/user/
$ ln -s ../client build/client 
$ stat build/client/index.js
stat: <outputs file stats>
```

Is this the intended behavior and please explain why...

Comment: this has probably something to do with th efact that using ../ use absolute path to declare path instead of relative path. a good pratice is to always use absolute path

Comment: I agree with the best practice as I've always used absolute paths for both the target and the destination. However, the man pages state that relative paths can be used for both...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the one that doesn't work, if we look at the `ls -l` result, we get the following:

```
[sparticvs@sparta test]$ ls -l build/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 sparticvs sparticvs 6 Dec 17 16:08 client -> client
```

Now to understand what is going on here. Let's look at the command you called:

```
ln -s client build/client
```

According to the Man Page, there are two possible matches for this format

```
SYNOPSIS
       ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
       ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
```

It will match on the first form (since its first).  Now, the "target name" or `client` in your case, can be (according to the complete `ln` manual) arbitrary strings.  They don't have to resolve to anything right now, but can resolve to something in the future.  What you are creating with your invocation is a "dangling symlink" and the system does not keep you from creating these.

Now your second invocation `ln -s ../client build/client` is what is called a "relative symlink" (as you noted in your own post).  There is a second type and that is an "absolute symlink" which would be called by doing `ln -s /home/user/client build/client`.

This is **not** a bug.  According to the manual it states:

> When creating a relative symlink in a different location than the
>   current directory, the resolution of the symlink will be different
>   than the resolution of the same string from the current directory.
>   Therefore, many users prefer to first change directories to the
>   location where the relative symlink will be created, so that
>   tab-completion or other file resolution will find the same target as
>   what will be placed in the symlink.
>
> -- from `info coreutils 'ln invocation'`

That said, you **MUST** use either the relative or absolute path to the target.

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed the intended behavior. From the `ln(1)` man page:

> Symbolic links can hold arbitrary
>          text; if later resolved, a relative link is interpreted in relation  to
>          its parent directory.

As to the why of it, imagine if the symlink were instead interpreted relative to its source rather than its destination. When later resolving it, you would need to know what your CWD was when you created it, which is nonsensical, let alone impossible.

Moreover, this way you get a neat and compact method to create a skeleton directory structure that you can drop anywhere in the directory tree without breaking the symlinks.

To give you an example of what I mean, let's say you're working on a project and you have a whole directory structure set up for it like so:

```
$ ls -1 /home/you/project
thingummies/
widgets/
wizardry/
```

Now suppose you wanted to create a symlink to `widgets/` inside `wizardry/`. You have two options:

```
$ ln -s /home/you/project/widgets /home/you/project/wizardry
```

or

```
$ ln -s ../widgets /home/you/project/wizardry
```

If you then try moving `/home/you/project` anywhere else, a symlink created with the first form will break because it's looking for `/home/you/project/widgets`. The second form will keep the symlink functional because it's looking for `../widgets` *relative* to the place it's in, regardless of where that place might be in the directory tree.