# Creating symbolic links

Tags: symlink, ln

When creating a softlink how do add the path, I did the following:

```
ln -s file1.txt /home/user9000/Desktop/SymbolicLink.txt
```

When I see the softlink on the desktop it marks that the doc doesn't exist.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to use the full path of the file to which you're linking.

Comment: To create a relative link, and have auto-completion help you, then first cd to directory that you want the link in. Then `ln -s ../../a/b/c` or `ln -s -T ../../a/b/c link`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of `ln` may seem counter-intuitive at first until you see the rationale behind it.

The syntax (for soft link creation) is

```
ln -s <TARGET> <LINK_NAME>
```

where `<TARGET>` is interpreted [relative to the location of the soft link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/105637/26909).

So when you say something like:

```
ln -s file1.txt /home/user9000/Desktop/SymbolicLink.txt
```

This means create the file `/home/user9000/Desktop/SymbolicLink.txt` as a symbolic link to the file `/home/user9000/Desktop/file1.txt`.

My guess is, you're trying to link to `file1` which is in the current working directory. In such a case, you'll need to give its full path as in [vinc17's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149436/26909)

Note that if you create `SymbolicLink.txt` with the command you have shown above, it has the interesting side effect that whenever you move it to any other directory, it will be a symbolic link to a file named `file1` in *that* directory. Whereas if you supply the full path to `file1`, the link will always point to that file no matter where you place it in that machine.

Answer (score 2):

Your link is incorrect. You need:

```
ln -s "$PWD/file1.txt" /home/user9000/Desktop/SymbolicLink.txt
```

You can also create a relative link (starting with `../`), but I suggest that you `cd` to `/home/user9000/Desktop` first to avoid making a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the UI behaves differently. A softlink won't be shown as a icon in desktop. You need to copy and paste the file there or create a link using the graphical interface itself.

Comment: i see. I thought i would be behave as a shortcut

Comment: What OS and UI are you talking about? On all Linux distros I have dealt with, a softlink is shown as an icon in the directory where it's placed.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I did the same long ago :)

Comment: @joseph-r we're talking about Ubuntu's Unity. If you create a symbolic link in the Desktop folder, it won't show in your desktop area.